# Azure Build Pipeline Get latest tag from from git repo

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a build pipeline and the first task is a PowerShell script which sets some variables. I have the git command to get the latest tag from a branch in the repo.

`git tag -l v* | tail -n1`

I am trying to use this to add to the build name. The command above has the output of: `v1.4.0`

However when I run:

```
$AppVersion= (git tag -l v* | tail -n1)
Write-host $AppVersion
```

I am getting the following error:

> tail : The term 'tail' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
>   function,  script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the
>   name, or if a path  was included, verify that the path is correct and
>   try again.

Comment: A PowerShell `tail -n 1` equivalent is `Select-Object -Last 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have manage to figure a workaround from the Tail error I was seeing.

```
$TagArray= git tag -l v*
$AppVersion = $TagArray[$TagArray.Count – 1]
```

I add the results returned from: `git tag -l v*` into an array and then I select the last element from that array.

Comment: `$TagArray[-1]` also grabs the last element.

Comment: ooo Thank You.  Ill make that change now

Comment: ##[error]invalid argument "***/lancer-api:git tag -l v*" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format

Answer (score 2):

You can use Git Describe to get the latest tag

```
$AppVersion= (git describe --match "v*" <BranchName>)
```

Comment: But he wants only tags that started with `v`.

Comment: As per his description - "I have the git command to get the latest tag from a branch in the repo"